# Is Predicate<T> not available in .NET 3.0+

Tags: .net, generics, .net-3.5, predicate

Is Predicate available anywhere in .NET?  From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx, I don't see a Predicate anywhere.  I see an anonymous that returns a boolean but no generics or a "Predicate" keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than inline a delegate for the predicate, you could use it as a type then pass it in. Here's an example:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
Predicate<int> p = delegate(int i)
                   {
                      return i < 5;
                   };
list.RemoveAll(p);
list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

**EDIT:** to declare the Predicate with an existing method, you would use:

```
Predicate<int> p = IsLessThanFive;

public bool IsLessThanFive(int number)
{
    return number < 5;
}
```

The alternatives, which are more common, would've been:

```
list.RemoveAll(delegate(int i) { return i < 5; });
// or...
list.RemoveAll(i => i < 5);
```

**EDIT:** to answer your other question in a comment to another post, a delegate is a type that defines a method signature and can be used to pass methods to other methods as arguments. If you're somewhat familiar with C++, they are like function pointers. For more info on delegates check out [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`Predicate` is a *type* (more specifically, a delegate type) in the `System` namespace. It’s not a keyword.

Comment: If it is a type, then why isn't Predicate<T> used in the example?  Are there any examples that use it?  What is a delegate type vs just a type?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely in 3.0... see the bottom of that MSDN page:

### Version Information

#### .NET Framework

**Supported in:** 3.5, 3.0, 2.0

As long as you are 'using System' you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

[That page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) is about the Predicate(T) Delegate, which as it states:

> Represents the method that defines a
>   set of criteria and determines whether
>   the specified object meets those
>   criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The Predicate **Type** is there in 3.5 and in 4.0.